# Rendered HTML on my page is different from PrimeFaces showcase page

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, firebug

I'm trying to use a primefaces [Element Layout](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutElement.jsf).

I've inserted the code that was provided in the above link to my xhtml page (so that code is now nested within other primefaces components...).

Here is the code that I got from the above link:

```
<p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout">  
    <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100" minSize="40" maxSize="200">  
        West  
    </p:layoutUnit>  

    <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
        Center  
    </p:layoutUnit>  
</p:layout>
```

However, the layout is not rendered properly. For example, it has `"visibility: hidden;"`.

I tried to compare the html in the above link, to the html that was created in my page.

Here is the relevant html that is created in the above link:

```
<div id="layout" class="ui-layout-container" style="min-width: 400px; min-height: 200px; overflow: visible; position: relative;">
    <div id="j_idt18" class="ui-layout-unit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-layout-west ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-west" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 0px; right: auto; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 194px; z-index: 0; width: 94px; display: block; visibility: visible;">
        <div class="ui-layout-unit-content ui-widget-content" style="position: relative; height: 191px; visibility: visible;"> West </div>
    </div>
    <div id="j_idt20" class="ui-layout-unit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-layout-center ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-center" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 107px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; height: 194px; width: 792px; z-index: 0; display: block; visibility: visible;">
        <div class="ui-layout-unit-content ui-widget-content" style="position: relative; height: 191px; visibility: visible;"> Center </div>
    </div>
    <div id="j_idt18-resizer" class="ui-layout-resizer ui-layout-resizer-west ui-layout-resizer-open ui-layout-resizer-west-open" style="position: absolute; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-size: 1px; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; z-index: 2; cursor: w-resize; left: 100px; height: 201px; width: 6px; top: 0px;" title="Resize" aria-disabled="false"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the html that is created in my page:

```
<div id="form:tabView:tabViewExceptions:layout" style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;">
    <div id="form:tabView:tabViewExceptions:j_idt113" class="ui-layout-unit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-layout-west">
        <div class="ui-layout-unit-content ui-widget-content"> West </div>
    </div>
    <div id="form:tabView:tabViewExceptions:j_idt115" class="ui-layout-unit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-layout-center">
        <div class="ui-layout-unit-content ui-widget-content"> Center </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So that explains to me why the Layout does not work on my page.

But why does the same JSF code create different html (if you ignore that different id's, which make sense)?

Why does the style on some of the `div`s in the link have properties which do not appear in the style created in my page?

How do I fix this?

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of PF showcase page to see exact PF version being used on showcase. Are you using exactly the same PF version?

Comment: No... I'm using PF 3.4.2 and theme Blitzer 1.0.9, in PF showcase they use PF 3.6-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Obvious step would be to rule out the version from making the difference.

Comment: I rebuilt the project with PF-3.6-SNAPSHOT, but still the same problem...

Comment: Wait, you've this in a `<p:tabView>`? What if you just put it as sole component straight inside the `<h:body>`?

Comment: In that case I see the Layout, and also the rendered HTML is very much like what I see in the PF showcase. I am not sure how PF internals work, but should the created html (other than id's) be different based on the parent component??

Comment: Okay... looks to me like another nasty bug.